# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - in Angular2 application

Tags: php, json, angular, angular2-services

Im writing an Angular2 application with php backend. When I make a request to the server from the angular application, it sends me this error message in the browser console.

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have read a question regarding this problem. They say the problem is with the response type of the `http` response. They say that, response type should be `json`. But response type is `text/html` in my application.

This is the service.ts file related to my problem `user.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../models/user';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private currentUser: User;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.currentUser = new User(null, null, null, false);
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.currentUser;
  }

  logIn(username, password) {
    let curUser = new User(username, password, null, false);

    this.http.post('http://localhost/back_End/controllers/user.php/', {'username': username , 'password': password})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        users => {
          curUser = users[0];
          console.log(curUser);
        }
      );
    console.log(curUser);
}
```

Problem is related to the `logIn` method.

This is the corresponding php file `user.php`

```
<?php
$data  = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

$server_ame = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "yathra";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "select * from user where username='$data->username' and password='$data->password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($data);

$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm new to Angular2. Can someone give me a solution for this?

Comment: Your angular is expecting a JSON response but in some cases your PHP will not return JSON, e.g. `echo "0 results";`

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, it sounds like the response you are getting from the server is HTML, probably a 404 page or some other page.  You should be able to open up the developer tools and view the response from the server in the network tab.  If that response isn't pure JSON, it won't work.

Comment: how to see original data coming from the server without parsing it?network tab shows only the headers of response and request. @Jason Spradlin

Comment: Check your network tab, click the request, and see what you are receiving in the 'Response' tab

Comment: and by the way, you are echoing two responses... so at least that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may Try For this:

The problem was here,because of you use json() instead of json

1. **json()** - always return json
2. **json** - always return text(that may be HTML,PHP,XHTML etc).

   this.http.post('http://localhost/back_End/controllers/user.php/',
            {'username': username , 'password': password})
                     .map(res => res.json) // SEE HERE
                     .subscribe(
                       users => {
                         curUser = users[0];
                         console.log(curUser);
                       }
                     );

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this error because you are attempting to parse a file as if it is JSON, which it isn't:

`.map(res => res.json())`

Try logging your response before running `res.json` and you'll see that it's a non-JSON file that begins with the `<` character (such as php, XML, HTML etc).

Comment: how to do that?is there a way to see raw data coming with response?

Comment: `.map(res => console.log(res))`

Comment: im sorry.but it doesn't work. nothing prints as the console output. i can't understand what is the error in this code. but when i give this 
 `console.log(this.http.post('http://localhost/back_End/controllers/user.php/', {'username': username , 'password': password}));` or `console.log(this.http.post('http://localhost/back_End/controllers/user.php/', {'username': username , 'password': password})
      .map(res => console.log(res)));`. It prints some object called _observable_.

Comment: did you forgotten the "port", e.g. (http://localhost:4200/...)? All this.http.post is a Observable. If the URL is wrong, you received a Status Code 404 -or a page- Try to send a post with the url you have -using developer tools in a navigator,e.g.

Comment: Try dropping this in to help debug:    `this.http.post('http://localhost/back_End/controllers/user.php/', {'username': username , 'password': password})
      .subscribe({
        next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
        error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
        complete: () => console.log('done'),
});`